# Remove directory files based on path from a csv

Tags: powershell

I have a csv that contains file paths and files names (and a few other fields).  How can I delete the files in the directory using the paths from my file?

Comment: Honesty?  nothing yet.  I'm pretty new to the Powershell world.  Google hasn't been my friend for this one today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the file and use the `Remove-Item` cmdlet. Assuming you have a column named "Path" that holds the full path to the file:

```
Import-Csv .\files.Csv | Foreach-Object{
   Remove-Item -LiteralPath $_.Path -Force
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I'll give that a try,  I've seen things regarding the Remove-Item command and I believe the -WhatIf command...? I'll give those a try together!

Comment: You can add -What to see what would have happened if you executed the command without it